# POST запрос к php скрипту. Помогите написать код

Tags: php, java, android, post

Здравствуйте! Имеется PHP скрипт, есть ссылка на него. Он на вход получает 2 значение: username и password, которые в приложении берутся из полей ввода (их я взял). Задача вот в чем: надо сформировать пост запрос к этому скрипту, положив туда параметры username и password. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В `AndroidManifest.xml` перед тегом `application` добавляете строчку:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Собственно, код:

```
public class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String address = strings[0];
        String username = strings[1];
        String password = strings[2];

        try {
            URL obj = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            String urlParameters = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catch exceptions
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Запускается вот так:

```
String responce =  new PostRequest().execute("http://www.example.com/script.php", "username", "password").get();
```

Comment: А как мне установить не английский а русский язык?
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.5"); - так?

Comment: @Егор, Язык чего?